# What is the difference between $\min(x_1,x_2)$ and $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$?

Tags: optimization, economics, utility

This question refers to microeconomic utility optimization where the utility function is Leontief. Are $\min(x_1,x_2)$ and $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$ interchangeable, or is there a difference?

edit: I interpret $\min(x_1,x_2)$ as the minimum of $x_1$ and $x_2$, i.e. if $x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow min(x_1,x_2) = x_1$ and $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$ is Leontief (complementary goods) which means that you need both goods to produce an output level $y$, thus even if $x_1<x_2$ you need both and $\min\{x_1,x_2\} \ne x_1$.

Comment: I'd assume they are the same, that the only difference is typographic.

Comment: The same, the first is a list, the second a set.

Comment: thank you! I edited my question, I hope you can help me on this.
Shoudn't there be a difference in this case?

Comment: If you need both goods to produce an output, and you have $x_1$ of one good and $x_2$ of the other good and $x_1<x_2$, why can't you produce $x_1$ output?

Comment: @Rahul $x_1$ and $x_2$ are input goods, and $y$ is the output. You could apply it such that $x_1$ is labor and $x_2$ is capital. You can't produce output just with one input factor.

Comment: So why can't you use all $x_1$ labor and only $x_1$ out of the $x_2$ capital to produce $x_1$ output?

Comment: For complementary goods you need both factors in a fixed ratio. For example you need one hour of labor and $\$100$ to produce a paper. You could use \$ 200 but you would not get two papers out of it, since you need an additional hour of labor, thus it would be a waste of input factors and you solely use the perfect ratio (under the constraint that labor and capital is costly).

Comment: @MarkusHauschel Another example: For a chair you need 1 wooden board and 12 nails. Now you have to adjust  $x_2$ so that  the nails are not overrated. The production function is $$\min\left(x_1, \frac1{12}x_2\right)$$ Is it comprehensible?

Comment: @callculus great example for a Leontief production function!
How does your example contribute to the comprehension between $min(o)$ and $min\{o\}$?
Is your suggestion that there is no difference between round and curly brackets, i.e. they are interchangeable?

Comment: @MarkusHauschel I agree to the comment of Wuestenfux. In your this case they are interchangeable.

Comment: @callculus thx. How would you write the minimum of two numbers if not like this: if $x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow \min(x_1,x_2)=x_1$ ?

Comment: @MarkusHauschel The same like you. Mostly there is no condition. One has just to calculate the minimum of $x_1$ and $x_2$.  The short notation is $\min(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your expertise. @callculus